# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int / NOT IN subquery

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT Br.BusinessDivision,B.BookingDate, B.DepartureDate, B.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.SurName
FROM Booking B
    INNER JOIN Customer C
        ON C.ContactID = B.ContactID
    INNER JOIN Branch Br
        ON Br.BranchID = B.BranchID
WHERE B.BookingDate
      BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2018-04-26'
      AND Br.BusinessDivision IN ( 'Retail', 'TVSales' )
      AND B.ContactID NOT IN (
                                 SELECT B.DepartureDate FROM Booking B WHERE B.DepartureDate >= '2018-04-26'
                             );
```

The Following SQL Statement is giving me the following error:  `error Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int`

Both the date columns `B.BookingDate` and `B.DepartureDate` are datatype `date` and not `int` so I'm unsure as to why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

`AND B.ContactID NOT IN ( SELECT B.DepartureDate`

You are comparing `ContactID`, presumably an int, to `DepartureDate`, presumably a date.

I think you wanted:

```
AND B.ContactID NOT IN
(
    SELECT B.CustomerID FROM Booking B
    WHERE B.DepartureDate >= '2018-04-26'
);
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong, yep! Comparing `ContactID` to the completely wrong column (doh). Have a similar `DepartureDate` column that is type `int` rather than `date`. Thanks!